# Java-CSV Date using Csv parser

Tags: java

I have a CSV file I'm trying to import using java. File with date column and dates in different formats I'd like to parse dates suitable for myqsl.

My code as:

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader().withDelimiter(',');
CSVParser parsernew =CSVParser(File, format)
List<CSVRecord> csvRecordList = parser.getRecords();
String cellvalue=csvRecordList.get(0);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dateFormat .parse(cellvalue);
```

I'm trying to parse date column value but got Exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
```

date column values as likes

```
10/31/2014
12/13/2013
2001-02-04
7/27/2001
2001-02-04
5/15/2008
```

Is there any way to parse different date formats and date format changes run time time how to handle that..

in excel

Thanks!

Comment: Try this.. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html) there's a section on parsing

Comment: Looks like you need an intermediate step to sanitize the data.

Comment: Thank you, folks.Yes i need an intermediate step. In link parse section pattern is fixed every time like that(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy");) . I m searching for all or most of the pattern dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fix the source of data

Firstly, you should educate the publisher of this data about **using only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats** when serializing date-time values as text. For a date-only without time-of-day and without time zone, that would be YYYY-MM-DD.

## Attempt parsing each of the two known formats

Fortunately, your example data shows only two formats: the standard YYYY-MM-DD format, and M/D/YYYY.

So try parsing with a pair of formatters, one for each case. If both fail, throw an exception to alert you to the publisher’s unfortunate use of even more formats.

### java.time

Use only *java.time* classes. Never use the terrible old date-time classes such as `Date` and `DateFormat`. Those legacy classes were supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310 in Java 8 and later.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Define the pair of formatters. The standard one is already defined as a constant: [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE). Define the other.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu" ) ;
```

Get your input string in your code using the [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library. But your code looks wrong in the Question. You need to add a loop for each of the `CSVRecord` objects in your list. Then extract each column from each row represented by that object.

```
CSVRecord record = = csvRecordList.get( i ) ;  // Fetch nth object from list.
String cellvalue = csvRecordList.get( 0 ) ;    // Extract each column/cell from each row/object. Must use annoying zero-based index counting.
```

### Catch `DateTimeParseException`

Attempt to parse the input using each of the two formatters using [`LocalDate.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)). Catch the `DateTimeParseException`.

```
LocalDate ld = null;

if( Objects.isNull( ld ) ) {
    try {
        ld = LocalDate.parse( cellvalue , DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE ) ;
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        // Swallow this particular exception in this particular case.
    }
}

if( Objects.isNull( ld ) ) {
    try {
        ld = LocalDate.parse( cellvalue , f ) ;
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        // Swallow this particular exception in this particular case.
    }
}

if( Objects.isNull( ld ) ) {
    // Yikes! Failing all parsing attempts above means we encountered an unexpected format. 
    // FIXME: Handle this error scenario.
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleFlatMapper](https://simpleflatmapper.org/0101-getting-started-csv.html) to define different date formats.

As an example:

```
CsvParser.mapWith(CsvMapperFactory.newInstance()
    .addColumnProperty(k -> k.getName().toLowerCase().contains("date"), new DateFormatProperty("dd/MM/yyyy"))
    .addColumnProperty(k -> k.getName().toLowerCase().contains("date"), new DateFormatProperty("dd-MM-yyyy"))
    .newMapper(Trade.class))
    .stream(reader).collect(toList());
```